Trying to run basic C++ Program and it won't run on VSCode
So I am completely brand new to C++ and learning the basics I watched a YouTube video to help me set up VSC and C++ correctly and initially it was working, I was running programs and the output was showing in the terminal.
However, on this specific program whilst I am trying to implement a while loop, the code simply wont run.
            #include <iostream>

            int main()
            {
                int x = 1;
                int number;

                while(x <= 5){
                    std::cin >> number;
                    x ++;
                }

                return 0;

  PS C:\Users\Rolla> cd "c:\Users\Rolla\" ; if ($?) { g++ 
  ProgramLoop.cpp -o ProgramLoop } ; if ($?) { .\ProgramLoop }. 


I repeatedly get this error every time I press the run code button.
I have tried to reboot my PC, close VSCode and restart it on task manager and honestly I am such a beginner to C++ and programming as a whole but I can't see any syntax errors that I done in terms of semi colons or parenthesis etc.

post text here, in the question. do not post images or links.

Please replace those images with text. For many good reasons, images of text will kill what could otherwise be a good question

Sorry I was not aware, I legit made my stack overflow account 15 minutes ago, I appreciate the heads up regarding the rules about images and links.

The code you have written is working perfectly without any issues. The main issue with this code is that it is not structured to achieve any specific output or functionality beyond accepting five integer inputs from the user. In order to see the results in the output/terminal section, you must have to update the code accordingly,
You can achieve that by adding a small output function into the code, as given in the below example,
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int number;

    while (x <= 5) {
        std::cin >> number;
        std::cout << "Number: " << number << std::endl;
        x++;
    }

    return 0;
}


std::cout is being used for displaying the value of the variable.
std::endl is being used to change the line.

Output of the code can be,
Number: 3

For more help, you can refer to the following websites (personal preference)
C++ reference
Geeks for Geeks
I hope it helped you :>

Thanks I appreciate this I was genuinely so confused.

@peabrain No issues, I am glad that I could help :>
(Please upvote if you find it helpful :>)

I don't understand this answer. Even though the original program was not producing any output it should have paused to accept input from the user and apparently that was not happening. So I'm not seeing the suggestion here as a solution to the original problem.

I posted what I wanted the program to do maybe that can help you.

@john The code is working as I tried to run it locally on my device. The issue was that, since there is no output text message, the input for the code has to be done in the blank terminal. Which couldn't be see which is why the user thought the code wasnt working.

@john I reported him for using LLM generated answers and he has deleted those since. Who knows.

"The main issue with this code is that it is not structured to achieve any specific output" - this is just bonkers. OP is not even asking for output. Use your wits, not AI.

@TedLyngmo Well I understand that and I havent used AI or something like that. The main issue is that I myself dont understand what the OP wants, which is why I just suggested a way to atleast show up something according to them.

#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int x = 1;
    int number;
    int total = 0;

    while(x <= 5){
        std::cout << "Please enter a number " << std::endl ;
        std::cin >> number;
        total = total + number;
        x++;
    }

    std::cout << "Your total is " << total << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The part that I was forgetting was the enter a number please.

Are you saying this works for you?

Yes this works.

This is strange. Your original code should also have worked then. It should've paused and let you input the numbers, while on the screenshot I don't see that. Weird...

please do not post code only answers. Explain what you changed and why and how this fixes the original issue.

I thought that my original code was missing the "cout" asking for a number to be entered. Do you think it should have let me put input regardless?

"Do you think it should have let me put input regardless?" yes. std::cin >> number; waits for the user to type input, regardless of any output produced before

Damn. Then I guess I still don't know what went wrong.
